# textarea data entry check with alert if empty

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, textarea

I have a form that has a **textarea** field for input.  I want an alert to pop up if the field is empty on submit.

I copied some code that works fine on an **input** field; however, it does not work for the **textarea** (it submits with no alerts whether empty or not).
I read through some other questions posted here and made some modifications.
Now, it alerts when empty, but it also alerts when there is text and does not submit.
I am new to this. I am using asp classic.

Code:

```
<form method="post" action="reasonProcess.asp" name="formName"  onSubmit="return Validate()">
<table >
<tr>
<td>Please enter a reason for the change:<br>
<textarea style="width:675px;height:75px" rows="12" cols="10" name="changereason" > <%=dbchangereason%> </textarea></td>
</tr>
</table><br>    
<input type=button value="Approve" onClick="javascript:saveAndSubmit()" class="btn" style="float:none;font-size:.78em;">
</form>

<script>
function saveAndSubmit()
{
     // Check for reason entered.
  if (!document.formName.changereason.value == '')
  {
    alert("Enter a reason.");
    return false;
  }
    var queryString = "reasonProcess.asp?Approve=Yes";
    document.formName.action=queryString;
    document.formName.submit();
    // window.close();

 }
</script>
```

This is line of code that works properly with the **input** text field:

```
  if (!document.formName.changereason.value)
```

I have also tried:

```
 if (!document.formName.changereason.value.length == 0)
```

and get the alert without text and with text.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look to my answer there's an Fiddle of working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

> '**!**' is the [logical not operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.9) in JavaScript.

The condition in your code say if the value of `changereason` textarea is **not empty** show `alert()` because of the `!` sign that mean **not**, but what you want is the contrary (if field is empty then show alert), so try just to remove the sign and it will work, do the follow change :

Replace :

```
if (!document.formName.changereason.value == '')
{
     alert("Enter a reason.");
     return false;
}
```

By :

```
if (document.formName.changereason.value == '') //removing the ! sign in this line
{
     alert("Enter a reason.");
     return false;
}
```

See **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mym6rzx/1/)**.

If that not work take a look at **[External simple page with the same code](http://goo.gl/eiUsz6)** that is not a fiddle and it should work also in your machine, code of external example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title></title>head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="reasonProcess.asp" name="formName"  onSubmit="return Validate()">
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>Please enter a reason for the change:<br>
                        <textarea style="width:675px;height:75px" rows="12" cols="10" name="changereason" > <%=dbchangereason%> </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>    
            <input type=button value="Approve" onClick="javascript:saveAndSubmit()" class="btn" style="float:none;font-size:.78em;">
        </form>

        <script>
            function saveAndSubmit()
            {
                 // Check for reason entered.
                if (document.formName.changereason.value == '')
                {
                     alert("Enter a reason.");
                     return false;
                }

                var queryString = "reasonProcess.asp?Approve=Yes";
                document.formName.action=queryString;
                document.formName.submit();
                // window.close();

             }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If that work and not the first example then maybe you have another part of code tha caused a problem and that is not referenced in the question.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. I did try removing the "!" but when I tested, it did not alert me and submitted the form anyway -- it seems to work in the Working fiddle though.  Have any suggestions?

Comment: That strange, updating my answer, take a look.

Comment: Hi - that helped! It works properly if I use either   
(document.formName.changereason.value == '')  or  (!document.formName.changereason.value).  Apparently the issue was trying to populate the field using the variable  <%=dbchangereason%> if one was stored in the database.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 if (!document.formName.changereason.value == '')
 {
alert("Enter a reason.");
return false;
 }
```

to

```
 if (document.formName.changereason.value == '')
 {
alert("Enter a reason.");
return false;
  }
```

The `!` means "not" - so you were saying if the value is *not* empty then alert.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your "change to" block of code is identical to the "change from" block of code...

Comment: @Martha oops haha. Not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 0):

In form tag write

```
<form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
```

This is your input field

```
<textarea name="reviewValue"></textarea>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form ){
  if (form.reviewValue.value == "") {
    alert( "Please choice your Rating." );
    form.reviewValue.focus();
    return false ;
  }
  return true ;
}
</script>
```